# what is the best way of route dynamically with extra parameter on the end

Tags: routes, nuxt.js

Right now its setup like this pages/user/_id/index (this path is /user/15)

but i would like to add an extra parameter like this

pages/user/_id/documents/index (this path is /user/15/documents)

this does work, but it only works if i am routing from user/15 page, if I just want to go straight to the other page (hence copy paste the link) then it just goes to /user/15

am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to answer it for anyone that might have the same issue, although mine was unusual..

the issue was that the programmer before me added some tabs and it was basically a hidden field.